# Generator expression must be parenthesized on a constraint

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to write:

`f = model.addConstr(E["1","5"] <= x["1"] for i in I, name="f")` by using a for loop on the "5".

So I wrote the following where the values of I are I=["1","5","4", "9","6","8","2","3","7"]

`f = model.addConstr(E["1",i] <= x["1"] for i in I, name="f")`

But I keep getting the error SyntaxError: **Generator expression must be parenthesized** and I don't know why.

Also, I am trying to add and if statement so when E["1","1"] it would just be zero. I tried by writing:

`f = model.addConstr(E["1",i] <= x["1"] for i in I if i != "1", name="f")`  but of course it doesn't work

But I am also trying with the following right before writing the constraint:

```
for i in I:
    if i == "1":
        E[i,i]=0
```

if anyone could give some guidance I would really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Your expression `E["1",i] <= x["1"] for i in I if i != "1"` is in the form of a list or generator comprehension, but without the wrapping `[]` for the list or `()` for the generator. Try either:

```
f = model.addConstr([E["1","5"] <= x["1"] for i in I], name="f")
```

or

```
f = model.addConstr((E["1","5"] <= x["1"] for i in I), name="f")
```

Comment: Also, as a stylistic point, `CAPITALIZED` variables in Python are generally used to correspond to constants, so `E` and `I` look a little out of place.